# rss in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, rss

Hi i want to include rss feeds in my winforms application and i want to show them in a panel with automatic scrolling from bottom to top (like in webapplications) is it possible? if so can you give me a simple example?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A very brief overview:

- Get rss schema from http://www.thearchitect.co.uk/schemas/rss-2_0.xsd
- Generate C# class using xsd.exe.

  xsd ***rssschema.xsd /c***
- Create a datagridview (turn on automatic scrolling)
- Bind the correct schema to the datagridview at compile time.
- Create a collection of rss object and set it as data source
- During runtime, make a http request and get rss feed (which should be a xml). Create a rss object out of this xml.Add it to the collection. (You will have to refer this link [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx))